# Update Constrains in order to have equal height for buttons IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Hy. I added in storyboard 3 buttons, one above the others like:
[image]

and I would like to update these buttons, in the following way:

Server side, I have the chance to enable or disable them. And I would like to update buttons if the last button is disabled, then hide it and update the other to in the way to fill the parent view. In the storyboard, i set up the buttons with equal height.
I tried to delete for the last button this constraint, and set it 0.0 but it doesn't work.

```
[self.constraintLeftBottom setConstant: 0.0];
[self.view removeConstraint:self.constraintLeftBottom];

[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

What i need to do ? In the image you will see how i was thinking. The parent view is set to fill the iPhones screen.

Thanks.

Comment: I see some circles, some rectangles, and some equal signs. I have no idea which of those are the buttons you're talking about. Anyway, by far the simplest solution, if you can target iOS 9, is to use a `UIStackView`, as it will handle the resizing automatically when you hide any of its arranged subviews.

Comment: @robmayoff The circles are the buttons :)